# How do I make these if statements scalable in C?

Tags: c, if-statement

This is my code. The goal is to convert the grayscale values to ASCII characters and print an image of Lena. I did it like this but my teacher said it isn't scalable, which is true. I'm relatively new to coding, so is there any way to make this shorter? I thought of using a for loop but can't figure out how.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lenaArray.h" //This library imports a 2D array of Lena

//Functions used in code;

char charGrayScale(int grayScale)
{
   //This function converts the grayscale values of every index array to a character in the ASCII
    if (grayScale < 25)  return ' ';
    if (grayScale < 50)  return '.';
    if (grayScale < 75)  return ':';
    if (grayScale < 100) return '-';
    if (grayScale < 125) return '=';
    if (grayScale < 150) return '+';
    if (grayScale < 175) return '*';
    if (grayScale < 200) return '#';
    if (grayScale < 225) return '%';
    return '@';
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "scalable"? One thing you can probably do here is to divide by 25 and use the resulting value as the index of an array

Comment: Does "scalable" mean you may want to have other intervalls than every 25? Like `[0..30]` => `' '`, `[31..48]` => `'.'` etc.? Or more than 9 different characters? Or both?

Comment: I should've explained a bit better yeah. By scalable I meant that there could be an issue if i had to work with more characters. Then I would've had to make a new if statement for a new character and that would go on forever.

Comment: @ZeroHunter1603 it's still not clear, please answer the first part of my question; if the answer is "no", then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74097602/898348) is the answer you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like a lookup table would be possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lenaArray.h" //This library imports a 2D array of Lena

//Functions used in code;

const char* GRAYSCALE_CHARS = {' ', '.', ':', '-', '=', '+', '*', '#', '%'};

char charGrayScale(int grayScale)
{
    const int index = (grayScale/25);
    if (index >= (sizeof(GRAYSCALE_CHARS)/sizeof(GRAYSCALE_CHARS[0]))) return '@';
    return GRAYSCALE_CHARS[index];
}
```

Comment: @KamilCuk Either `const char*` or `const char SOME_NAME[]`

Comment: Thanks! I was able to make it work and I learned something new with your help. Again you have my thanks!

Comment: No problem. You can select an answer as solution, so this question will be closed to prevent others from looking into your issue again. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by 'scalable' your teacher wants you to get rid of the hard-coded values, to be able to 'scale' your solution towards arbitrary integeger inputs (e.g. not bound to a fixed value 0-255).
This can be combined with a lookup table implementation as written in the previous answer by Louis Wilke.

E.g. something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lenaArray.h" //This library imports a 2D array of Lena

//Functions used in code;

const char greyscaleChars[] = {' ', '.', ':', '-', '=', '+', '*', '#', '%', '@'};

const char charGreyScale(int greyScale, int min, int max) {
    int step = (max - min) / (sizeof greyscaleChars);
    return greyscaleChars[greyScale/step - 1];
}
```

Please note I have not tested this code, it is just intended to show the idea.

Comment: Did you just copy my code including my typo?:D Compile time arrays in C are defined with `arr = { 1, 2, 3, ... }` not with `[]` braces

Comment: I sure did, thats why I mentioned you :D

Comment: Haha no problem :D I think it would be more flexible to divide by the length of the lookup array instead of a hard-coded 10?

Comment: Ah yes, also good point!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers depend on the values being spaced at 25-intervals.

I updated the same idea so that the interval does not need to be at regular spacing.  The limit of each interval is specified in the static table.

This does depend on the interval-limits being sorted in ascending order.
So if you have to add more entries to the table, be sure they're added in the right place.

```
#define COUNT_OF(x) ((sizeof(x)/sizeof(0[x])) / ((size_t)(!(sizeof(x) % sizeof(0[x])))))

char charGrayScale(int grayScale)
{
    static struct
    {
        int limit;
        char symbol;
    } grayMap[] = {
        { 25, ' ' },
        { 50, '.' },
        { 75, ':' },
        { 100, '-'},
        { 125, '='},
        { 150, '+'},
        { 175, '*'},
        { 200, '#'},
        { 225, '%'},
        { 250, '@'},
    };
    char symbol = grayMap[COUNT_OF(grayMap)-1].symbol;

    for(int i=0; i<COUNT_OF(grayMap); ++i)
    {
        if (grayScale < grayMap[i].limit)
        {
            symbol = grayMap[i].symbol;
            break;
        }
    }
    return symbol;
}
```